# missing icons with Snowpack + Svelte + svelte-materialify

Tags: material-design, svelte, snowpack

I am trying to get snowpack to work with svelte-materialify.
I created an app with `create-snowpack-app svelte-snowpack --template @snowpack/app-template-svelte`, followed by `yarn install svelte-materialify`.

All the CSS seem to work, a simple `MaterialApp` with a demo `AppBar` works: CSS, light/dark theme, animations etc. - except that the icons are completely missing. No error in Js console.

On the snoepack site, there are examples for webpack and rollup - these don't seem to be necessary for snowpack - the postcss plugin is already activated, and seems to do the trick here. So, everything fine, except for icons.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution
First you have to install the icons package

```
npm install --save svelte-icons
```

then you have to import each icon separately
Example

```
<script>
   import MdShoppingCart from 'svelte-icons/md/MdShoppingCart.svelte'
   <MdShoppingCart/>
</script>
```

For more icons enter this link
https://svelte-icons.vercel.app/

Choose a library, and click on the icon to get the import code
then use it as a tag